# date format change when year is an one digit number

Tags: r, date

I have a df with a date column (year month) like this: 7-Feb, 7-March ( meaning February 2007, March 2007 etc). I want to make it like this 2007-02, 2007-03 etc. I tried to solve it by this code

```
as.Date(df$date,format="%y-%b")
```

But it produces na na ...

As a new learner of r, could you help me in this regard?

Comment: A date must include a day or it isn't a date. R knows this.

Comment: but this output comes from r when I calculate monthly min, max values by daily data@Roland

Comment: Again, a month is not a date.

Comment: ok, it may not a particular date. but is it possible to change?@Roland

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `zoo::as.yearmon` function as:

```
library(zoo)

as.yearmon("7-Feb", "%y-%b")
#[1] "Feb 2007"


format(as.yearmon("7-Feb", "%y-%b"),"%m-%Y")
#[1] "02-2007"

#For OP's data.frame:

df$date <- as.yearmon(df$date, "%y-%b")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the code. I have many months like 7-Feb, 8-Mar, ....... and so on (Maybe over 500). Is it possible to change the whole column? because putting so many dates on the code like "7-Feb" would be time consuming.@MKR

Comment: Thank you so much. df$date <- as.yearmon(df$date, "%y-%b") this code is producing output like Feb 2007 Mar 2007

Comment: You can even try `df$date <- format(as.yearmon(df$date, "%y-%b"),"%Y-%m")`

Comment: great this code giving the output I wanted :df$date <- format(as.yearmon(df$date, "%y-%b"),"%Y-%m")

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to a add a day to your string like in this example:

```
as.Date(paste0("01-", "7-Feb"), "%d-%y-%b")
```

Here I am setting the date to the first of the month.  In your case one can replace "7-Feb" with your vector of strings.

Comment: Thank you for your advice and code. Can you give me the code by which I can add the day to the whole date column?

Comment: For example for a column named "date": `as.Date(paste0("01-", df$date), "%d-%y-%b")`